# clojure sorting map values alphabetically by a keyword

Tags: sorting, clojure, functional-programming

How would I sort

```
{
 {:name "d" :id 2}
 {:name "f" :id 3}
 {:name "a" :id 1}
 {:name "z" :id 9}
}
```

Alphabetically by name? Like this:

```
{
 {:name "a" :id 1}
 {:name "d" :id 2}
 {:name "f" :id 3}
 {:name "z" :id 9}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, be sure to look at [the Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).

In this case just use `sort-by`

```
(def data
  [{:name "d" :id 2}
   {:name "f" :id 3}
   {:name "a" :id 1}
   {:name "z" :id 9}])

(sort-by :name data) => 
  ({:name "a", :id 1}
   {:name "d", :id 2}
   {:name "f", :id 3}
   {:name "z", :id 9})
```

Note that I had to fix your data to use square brackets `[...]`

Comment: Thanks! How would I sort this in descending order?

Comment: `(sort-by :name #(compare %2 %1) data)`

Comment: Or `(sort-by :name > data)` would sort in descending order